# ajax resolve cross origin

Tags: json, ajax, raspberry-pi, cross-domain

basicly i have my working code.
I retrieve json data from a webserver with "https and digest authentication".

But, i can only get the data after I start chrome with this command:
"chrome.exe --user-data-dir="c:/chrome dev session" --disable-web-security"

So then i need to go manually to the webserver and accept the self signed certificate.

After that I get my JSON Data

I use this: https://github.com/Kynec/digest-ajax

and this is my code:

```
$.ajaxDigest('https://192.168.0.100/x',{
username: 'user',
password: 'pass'
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
alert('Retrieved data!');
alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert('Request failed :(');
});
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://user:pass@192.168.0.100/x' from origin 'http://192.168.0.111' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I get this working without chrome in this mode ?
I cant reconfigure every Browser, its for the clients

All is hosted at my raspberry pi with apache2 webserver

edit:

I tried to add

```
headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
```

in line 120 from digest-ajax.js

But I get error

digest-ajax.js:

```
(function($) {
DigestAjax = function() {};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      AuthHelper Function
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * This function is intended to be overriden to help supply credentials.
 * <p>
 * Instead of hard-coding a username/password in settings and passing 
 * it on each AJAX request, this method is called whenever a request 
 * is challenged for credentials. This method should return an Object 
 * with the username/password which will then be used to 
 * authenticate.
 * <p>
 * By default this method will return an empty username/password combo, 
 * but it can be overriden to prompt the user for a username and/or 
 * password.
 * @returns {Object} Object that must contain a 'username' and 
 *          'password' key/value pair
 */
DigestAjax.authHelper = function() {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      HA1/Username Store
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**Temporary storage of a generated HA1 value*/
DigestAjax.UNAUTH_HA1 = null;
/**
 * If Digest authentication succeeds, the temporary HA1 is transferred to 
 * this value, where it is used for future requests.
 */
DigestAjax.AUTH_HA1 = null;
/**Temporary storage of provided username*/
DigestAjax.UNAUTH_USERNAME = null;
/**
 * If Digest authentication succeeds, username is stored in this value for 
 * future requests.
 */
DigestAjax.AUTH_USERNAME = null;
/**
 * Value of the WWW-Authenticate header name to retrieve. This can be 
 * changed if the server is returning authentication information on a 
 * different header name value. This is commonly the case when avoiding 
 * built-in browser authentication prompts.
 */
DigestAjax.WWW_AUTHENTICATE = 'WWW-Authenticate';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//      Primary AJAX Digest Authentication Function
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Submits an AJAX request with optional credentials to handle 
 * Digest authentication.
 * @param {(String | Object)} url the URL of the request, or settings Object
 * @param {(Object | String)} settings settings Object, or username
 * @param {String} username username, or password if username was provided 
 *          instead of settings
 * @param {String} password password
 * @returns {Promise} promise interface to call back for AJAX results
 */
DigestAjax.ajaxDigest = function(url, settings, username, password) {
    //Settings, username, and password variables
    var s = {}, u, p;

    //Extract the path from the URL, which is used for qop
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof url === 'object') {
        //ajaxDigest(settings)
        s = url;
        a.href = s.url;
    }
    else if (typeof url === 'string') {
        if (typeof settings === 'string') {
            //ajaxDigest(url, username, password)
            u = settings ? settings : null;
            p = username ? username : null;
        }
        else if (typeof settings === 'object') {
            //ajaxDigest(url, settings, username, password)
            s = settings ? settings : {};
            u = username ? username : null;
            p = password ? password : null;
        }
        a.href = url;
        s.url = url;
    }

    s = $.extend({
        requestUri: a.pathname + a.search,
        username: u,
        password: p,
        type: 'GET'
    }, s);


    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    return dfd.promise(doAjaxUnauthorized());

    function doAjaxUnauthorized() {
        //If the request is successful, invoke callbacks immediately 
        //without using Digest authentication
        return $.ajax(s)
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                dfd.resolve(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //Only attempt Digest authentication on a 401/407 response
                if (jqXHR.status === 401 || jqXHR.status === 407) {
                    doAjaxAuthorized(createAuthorizationHeader(jqXHR));
                }
                else {
                    dfd.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
    }

    function doAjaxAuthorized(header) {
        if (s.headers === undefined) {
            s.headers = {};
        }
        s.headers.Authorization = header;
        return $.ajax(s)
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (DigestAjax.UNAUTH_HA1 !== null) {
                    DigestAjax.AUTH_HA1 = DigestAjax.UNAUTH_HA1;
                    DigestAjax.UNAUTH_HA1 = null;
                }
                if (DigestAjax.UNAUTH_USERNAME !== null) {
                    DigestAjax.AUTH_USERNAME = DigestAjax.UNAUTH_USERNAME;
                    DigestAjax.UNAUTH_USERNAME = null;
                }
                dfd.resolve(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 401 || jqXHR.status === 407) {
                    DigestAjax.AUTH_HA1 = null;
                    DigestAjax.AUTH_USERNAME = null;
                }
                dfd.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
    }

    function createAuthorizationHeader(xhr) {
        var header = xhr.getResponseHeader(DigestAjax.WWW_AUTHENTICATE);
        if (header !== undefined && header !== null) {
            var params = parseWWWAuthenticateHeader(header);

            var qop = params.qop;
            var clientQop = 'auth';
            if (qop !== undefined && qop.toLowerCase() === 'auth-int') {
                clientQop = 'auth-int';
            }

            //HA1 Calculation
            var algorithm = params.algorithm;
            var ha1;
            var username;
            var cnonce;
            if (DigestAjax.AUTH_HA1 !== null) {
                ha1 = DigestAjax.AUTH_HA1;
                username = DigestAjax.AUTH_USERNAME;
            }
            else {
                if (s.username === null || s.password === null) {
                    var auth = $.extend({
                        username: '',
                        password: ''
                    }, DigestAjax.authHelper());
                    $.extend(s, auth);
                }
                if (algorithm !== undefined && algorithm.toLowerCase() === 'md5-sess') {
                    cnonce = generateCnonce();
                    ha1 = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.MD5(s.username + ':' 
                            + params.realm + ':' + s.password) + ':' 
                            + params.nonce + ':' + cnonce);
                }
                else {
                    ha1 = CryptoJS.MD5(s.username + ':' + params.realm + ':' + s.password);
                }
                username = s.username;
                DigestAjax.UNAUTH_HA1 = ha1;
                DigestAjax.UNAUTH_USERNAME = s.username;
            }

            //HA2 Calculation
            var ha2, response;
            if (clientQop === 'auth-int') {
                var body = s.data ? s.data : '';
                ha2 = CryptoJS.MD5(s.type + ':' + s.requestUri + ':' + CryptoJS.MD5(body));
            }
            else {
                ha2 = CryptoJS.MD5(s.type + ':' + s.requestUri);
            }

            //Response Calculation
            var response, nc;
            if (params.qop === undefined) {
                response = CryptoJS.MD5(ha1 + ':' + params.nonce + ':' + ha2);
            }
            else {
                //Cnonce Calculation
                if (cnonce === undefined) {
                    //Cnonce may have been generated already for MD5-sess algorithm
                    cnonce = generateCnonce();
                }
                nc = '00000001';
                response = CryptoJS.MD5(ha1 + ':' + params.nonce + ':' 
                        + nc + ':' + cnonce + ':' + clientQop + ':' + ha2);
            }

            var sb = [];
            sb.push('Digest username="', username, '",');
            sb.push('realm="', params.realm, '",');
            sb.push('nonce="', params.nonce, '",');
            sb.push('uri="', s.requestUri, '",');
            sb.push('qop=', clientQop, ',');
            if (nc !== undefined) {
                sb.push('nc=', nc, ',');
            }
            if (cnonce !== undefined) {
                sb.push('cnonce="', cnonce, '",');
            }
            if (params.opaque !== undefined) {
                sb.push('opaque="', params.opaque, '",');
            }
            sb.push('response="', response, '"');
            return sb.join('');
        }
    }
    function parseWWWAuthenticateHeader(header) {
        var params = {};
        var regex = /([^"',\s]*)="([^"]*)/gm;
        var result = null;
        do {
            result = regex.exec(header);
            if (result !== null) {
                params[result[1]] = result[2];
            }
        }
        while (result !== null);
        return params;
    }
    function generateCnonce() {
        var cnonceChars = 'abcdef0123456789';
        var cnonce = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnonceChars.length);
            cnonce += cnonceChars.substr(randNum, 1);
        }
        return cnonce;
    }
};
DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType = function(type, url, settings, username, password) {
    if (typeof settings === 'string') {
        password = username;
        username = settings;
    }

    if (typeof settings !== 'object') {
        settings = {};
    }
    settings.type = type;
    return DigestAjax.ajaxDigest(url, settings, username, password);
};
DigestAjax.getDigest = function(url, settings, username, password) {
    return DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType('GET', url, settings, username, password);
};
DigestAjax.postDigest = function(url, settings, username, password) {
    return DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType('POST', url, settings, username, password);
};
DigestAjax.putDigest = function(url, settings, username, password) {
    return DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType('PUT', url, settings, username, password);
};
DigestAjax.deleteDigest = function(url, settings, username, password) {
    return DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType('DELETE', url, settings, username, password);
};
$.extend({
    authHelper: function(call) {
        DigestAjax.authHelper = call;
    },        
    ajaxDigest: DigestAjax.ajaxDigest,
    ajaxDigestType: DigestAjax.ajaxDigestType,
    getDigest: DigestAjax.getDigest,
    postDigest: DigestAjax.postDigest,
    putDigest: DigestAjax.putDigest,
    deleteDigest: DigestAjax.deleteDigest
});
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: You need set allow CORS in your API backend.

Comment: I tried to set this in my Apache config. But this wastn working. You mean at my javascript ?